# Ads randômicos entre células de uma Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Estou tentando inserir Ads **totalmente randômicos** entre células dentro de uma `UITableView`. É mais ou menos isso que eu quero:

[image: Randomly Ads]

Assim está meu **Table View Controller**:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class Page1: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @IBOutlet weak var GoogleBannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchBar.frame.height) //hide searchBar

        Shared.instance.employees.sort {
            (first, second) in
            first.name.compare(second.name, options: .diacriticInsensitive) == .orderedAscending
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 9 || indexPath.row == 14 {
            let cellAd = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellAd", for: indexPath)

            GoogleBannerView?.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-6043248661561548/4628935113"
            GoogleBannerView?.rootViewController = self
            GoogleBannerView?.load(GADRequest())

            return cellAd
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1

        if isSearching {
            cell.nameLabel.text = employeesSearching[indexPath.row].name
            cell.positionLabel.text = employeesSearching[indexPath.row].position
        } else {
            let letter = collation.sectionTitles[indexPath.section]
            let matches = getMatches(letter: letter, withArray: Shared.instance.employees)

            cell.nameLabel.text = matches[indexPath.row].name
            cell.positionLabel.text = matches[indexPath.row].position
        }
        return cell
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Gostaria que alguém pudesse me explicar o que eu devo fazer no `cellForRowAt` para que eu acrescentasse os Ads. Pois em meio aos indexed sections estou meio confuso.

---

**EDIT**

Esta é minha classe de TableViewCell atualmente:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell1: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var positionLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Cria uma outra célula com outro identifier pro anúncio. Retorna uma célula a mais por sessão. Aí checa se o `indexPath.row == 0` e se for usa a célula do add em vez da outra.

Comment: Consegui exibir as células da maneira que eu queria. Mas não consigo inserir um `GADBannerView` aí… Não sei onde estou errando. Editei minha pergunta para você ver como ficou. Não consigo associar o `@IBOutlet GoogleBannerView` ao Main.Storyboard.

Comment: Você tem que criar uma subclasse da `UITableViewCell`, usar essa classe pra célula dos anúncios e é nela que você vai adicionar a outlet e associar ao storyboard.

Comment: Desculpa o amadorismo, mas como eu crio essa subclasse? Pesquisei no Google mas não achei nada de útil. Também editei minha pergunta para lhe mostrar a estrutura atual de `TableViewCell`.

Comment: Cara, você vai ter que procurar tutoriais de como usar UITableView e treinar um pouco. Esse é o básico, e é muita coisa pra eu explicar aqui.

Comment: Esquenta não, já me ajudou pra caramba! Acho que eu consegui aqui. Brigadão

Comment: Legal, boa sorte aí. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para inserir os ADS Randomicos, eu indico que você modifique o array de dados que utiliza para montar a tableview, antes de exibir a tableview.

Para isto, voce poderia inserir os ADS no teu array de dados... ou dentro do metodo `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` juntamente com uma variavel `isAdsAdicionadas`; ou em algum metodo chamado por seu código ANTES do `numberOfRowsInSection`, no momento da instanciação da tela (eu, particularmente, prefiro esta abordagem)

Pelo que vi o array que você ta utilizando para isso é o `matches`

Entao poderia fazer mais ou menos isso:

Criar atributo `isAdsAdicionadas` e no `numberOfRowsInSection` verificar estado da variavel, se false, chama o metodo `inserirADSRandomicamente`:

```
let isAdsAdicionadas: Bool = false

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(isAdsAdicionadas == false){

        self.inserirADSRandomicamente()
    }

    isAdsAdicionadas = true

    return matches.count
}

func inserirADSRandomicamente(){

    var indiceRandomico: Int!
    var arrayIndiceRandomico:[Int] = []
    let numeroMaximoDeADS = 3
    var contador = 0

    func randomizar(){

        indiceRandomico = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(matches.count)))
        if(contador <= numeroMaximoDeADS){
            if(arrayIndiceRandomico.contains(indiceRandomico) == true){
                randomizar()
            }
            else{
                let objetoADS = "OBJETO ADS"
                matches.insert(objetoADS, at: indiceRandomico)
                arrayIndiceRandomico.append(indiceRandomico)
                contador += 1
                randomizar()
            }
        }
        else{
            return
        }
    }

    randomizar()
}
```

A partir dai, voce ja tem o array com os ADS randomicos. Basta tratar os casos de ser ADS ou não, no método `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Você pode adicionar mais logicas no metodo `randomizar()`, caso não queira exibir duas ADS seguidas, por exemplo.